# Insert text into a specific location in gwt textarea

Tags: java, gwt, textarea

In traditional java jTextArea we had the `insert(String value, int Postion)` method to insert text at a specific location. But i couldn't find the same functionality in the gwt equivalents.
I can take the whole string, insert what i want where i want it and then set the result back to the textarea but taking the whole text out and setting it back EVERYTIME doesn't seem very efficient. Is there a way of inserting the text at a location of my choice?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Formatter to insert HTML at the current cursor position.

```
    RichTextArea.Formatter formatter = myRichTextArea.getFormatter();
    formatter.insertHTML(html);
```

You still need to add your text to a String and replace TextArea contents if you need a different position. I don't think users will even notice this - it happens very fast.

Answer (score 0):

Woomma .. Our Gwt seniours came across all these brain storming issues and  implemented  some children libraries for us ..

I strongly beliving  you are looking for this and hope it will helpful for you

[Replace string for GWT](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/GWT/ReplacestringforGWT.htm)

All you need to do is just add the small method to your class and  use as

```
  String returnedString =  replace(text, searchString, replacement, -1);
```

Coming to your `EVERYTIME` replacing issue...   We have no other option as of now